# Working with classes in Python 3.8.2, Didn't get any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class Person():
    def insert(self,name,age,idName):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.idName=idName

    def output(self):
        print('name='+name+'\nage='+age+'\nidName='+idName)

j=Person()
j.insert('Alex','40','3143450603')
j.output
```

Nothing outputted in a terminal, maybe some syntax error

Comment: You're not *calling* the output method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in `output` method you have to access the variables with `self.`.

Secondly, you are caaling `output` method without braces which needs to be fixed.

Try this :

```
class Person():
    def insert(self,name,age,idName):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.idName=idName

    def output(self):
        print('name='+self.name+'\nage='+self.age+'\nidName='+self.idName)

j=Person()
j.insert('Alex','40','3143450603')
j.output()
```

This is the output you will get :

```
name=Alex
age=40
idName=3143450603
```

Answer (score 1):

In the method `Person.output()` you are referring to the local variables name, age and idName, whereas you should be referring to the object's members (self.name, ...), because the local variables do not exist at this point. They only existed in `Person.insert()`.